# Spring boot test not recognizing servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, junit, spring-boot-test

I have got Spring Boot Application and I want to test it. I do not use Spring Controllers, but I use Servlet with service method. Also I have got my configuration class that provides ServletRegistrationBean.
But every time when I try to perform mock request I get 404 error. There is no call to servlet at all. I think that Spring does not find this servlet. How could I fix it? While I am launching app at localhost everything works fine.

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SpringDataProcessorTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void retrieveByRequest() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(buildRetrieveCustomerByIdRequest("1")).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

    private MockHttpServletRequestBuilder buildRetrieveCustomerByIdRequest(String id) throws Exception {
        return get(String.format("/path/get('%s')", id)).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ODataConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public String urlPath = "/path/*";


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean odataServlet(MyServlet servlet) {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, new String[] {odataUrlPath});
    }
}
```

MyServlet:

```
@Component
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private ODataHttpHandler handler;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            handler.process(req, resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Server Error occurred", e);
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `MockMvc` for that. `MockMvc` holds an specific `DispatcherServlet` internally and is intended to be used for Spring MVC testing (meaning everything that lives inside the `DispatcherServlet`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use `MockMvc` to test your code instead of a `Servlet` use a `HttpRequestHandler` and use a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to map it to a URL.

Something like the following.

```
@Bean
public HttpRequestHandler odataRequestHandler(ODataHttpHandler handler) {
    return new HttpRequestHandler() {
        public void handleRequest() {
            try {
                handler.process(req, resp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Server Error occurred", e);
                throw new ServletException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for the mapping

```
@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setUrlMap(Collections.singletonMap(odataUrlPath, "odataRequestHandler"); 
    return mapping;
}
```

Another solution would be to wrap it in a controller instead of a servlet.

```
@Controller
public class ODataController {

    private final ODataHttpHandler handler;

    public ODataController(ODataHttpHandler handler) {
        this.handler=handler;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/path/*")
    public void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        try {
            handler.process(req, resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Server Error occurred", e);
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In either way your handler should be served/processed by the `DispatcherServlet` and thus can be tested using `MockMvc`.

Comment: SimpleUrlHandlerMapping does not work. But if @Bean(name="/path/*) specified above HttpRequestHandler everything works fine. But in this request servletPath field is empty. If I specify it via MockHttpServletRequestBuilder, request is not being handled again.

Comment: Why do you need the servlet path?

Comment: Servlet path is needed in OData processor. App fails without it.

Comment: Then you would need to map the `DispatcherServlet` at that path. However not sure if you want to do all that just to make this work. Why not simply test it with a `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse` and just get the servlet from the context and call the desired method.

Comment: That you a lot! I did it with that approach, but was wondering whether this work could be done through mockMvc :)